# How do I find the first and last datapoint for data spread across several rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, formatting

I have an SQL Server database table that looks like this

```
+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-----------------+------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+-------------------+
|            Signon Time            |      User Name       | Signon Duration | Pre Logon DND Duration |    Logon Time     | Pre Logoff Idle Duration | Logon Duration |    Logoff Time    |
+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-----------------+------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+-------------------+
| 15-09-20 8:56:06                  | Aaisha Alvi Scotts   | 29038           |                    460 | 15-09-20 9:03:46  |                        0 |           3401 | 15-09-20 10:00:26 |
| 15-09-20 8:56:06                  | Aaisha Alvi Scotts   | 29038           |                     16 | 15-09-20 10:00:42 |                        0 |           4991 | 15-09-20 11:23:53 |
| 15-09-20 8:56:06                  | Aaisha Alvi Scotts   | 29038           |                    671 | 15-09-20 11:35:04 |                        0 |           4709 | 15-09-20 12:53:32 |
| 15-09-20 8:56:06                  | Aaisha Alvi Scotts   | 29038           |                    138 | 15-09-20 12:55:51 |                        0 |            439 | 15-09-20 13:03:10 |
| 15-09-20 8:56:06                  | Aaisha Alvi Scotts   | 29038           |                     44 | 15-09-20 13:03:53 |                        0 |            265 | 15-09-20 13:08:19 |
| 15-09-20 8:56:06                  | Aaisha Alvi Scotts   | 29038           |                   1966 | 15-09-20 13:41:05 |                        0 |           6997 | 15-09-20 15:37:42 |
| 15-09-20 8:56:06                  | Aaisha Alvi Scotts   | 29038           |                     22 | 15-09-20 15:38:03 |                        0 |           1397 | 15-09-20 16:01:20 |
| 15-09-20 8:56:06                  | Aaisha Alvi Scotts   | 29038           |                    848 | 15-09-20 16:15:28 |                        0 |           1013 | 15-09-20 16:32:21 |
| 15-09-20 8:56:06                  | Aaisha Alvi Scotts   | 29038           |                      5 | 15-09-20 16:32:26 |                        0 |            387 | 15-09-20 16:38:52 |
| 15-09-20 8:56:06                  | Aaisha Alvi Scotts   | 29038           |                    221 | 15-09-20 16:42:33 |                        0 |            567 | 15-09-20 16:52:00 |
| 15-09-20 7:47:26                  | Aaron Haider         | 1006            |                    770 | 15-09-20 8:00:15  |                        0 |            234 | 15-09-20 8:04:10  |
| 15-09-20 8:04:29                  | Aaron Haider         | 1352            |                      0 | 15-09-20 8:04:29  |                        0 |              0 | 15-09-20 8:04:29  |
| 15-09-20 8:04:29                  | Aaron Haider         | 1352            |                     10 | 15-09-20 8:04:39  |                        0 |           1053 | 15-09-20 8:22:11  |
| 15-09-20 8:04:29                  | Aaron Haider         | 1352            |                     61 | 15-09-20 8:23:12  |                        0 |              0 | 15-09-20 8:23:12  |
| 15-09-20 8:04:29                  | Aaron Haider         | 1352            |                     61 | 15-09-20 8:24:13  |                        0 |              0 | 15-09-20 8:24:13  |
| 15-09-20 8:04:29                  | Aaron Haider         | 1352            |                     60 | 15-09-20 8:25:13  |                        0 |              0 | 15-09-20 8:25:13  |
| 15-09-20 8:25:33                  | Aaron Haider         | 27846           |                     11 | 15-09-20 8:25:44  |                        0 |           3317 | 15-09-20 9:21:01  |
| 15-09-20 8:04:29                  | Aaron Haider         | 1352            |                     61 | 15-09-20 8:26:14  |                        0 |             33 | 15-09-20 8:26:47  |
| 15-09-20 8:25:33                  | Aaron Haider         | 27846           |                    670 | 15-09-20 9:32:11  |                        0 |           1732 | 15-09-20 10:01:03 |
| 15-09-20 8:25:33                  | Aaron Haider         | 27846           |                    603 | 15-09-20 10:11:06 |                        0 |           3406 | 15-09-20 11:07:52 |
| 15-09-20 8:25:33                  | Aaron Haider         | 27846           |                    457 | 15-09-20 11:15:29 |                        0 |           2053 | 15-09-20 11:49:42 |
| 15-09-20 8:25:33                  | Aaron Haider         | 27846           |                     81 | 15-09-20 11:51:03 |                        0 |            716 | 15-09-20 12:03:00 |
| 15-09-20 8:25:33                  | Aaron Haider         | 27846           |                   1816 | 15-09-20 12:33:16 |                        0 |           3301 | 15-09-20 13:28:17 |
| 15-09-20 8:25:33                  | Aaron Haider         | 27846           |                    205 | 15-09-20 13:31:42 |                        0 |           1950 | 15-09-20 14:04:12 |
| 15-09-20 8:25:33                  | Aaron Haider         | 27846           |                    663 | 15-09-20 14:15:15 |                        0 |           2172 | 15-09-20 14:51:27 |
| 15-09-20 8:25:33                  | Aaron Haider         | 27846           |                    430 | 15-09-20 14:58:37 |                        0 |           4238 | 15-09-20 16:09:15 |
| 15-09-20 11:31:56                 | Adeel Hussain Scotts | 243             |                      0 | 15-09-20 11:31:56 |                        0 |            236 | 15-09-20 11:35:52 |
| 15-09-20 11:36:55                 | Adeel Hussain Scotts | 12546           |                   1748 | 15-09-20 12:06:03 |                        0 |            577 | 15-09-20 12:15:40 |
| 15-09-20 11:36:55                 | Adeel Hussain Scotts | 12546           |                   1760 | 15-09-20 12:45:01 |                        0 |            349 | 15-09-20 12:50:50 |
| 15-09-20 11:36:55                 | Adeel Hussain Scotts | 12546           |                   1437 | 15-09-20 13:14:47 |                        0 |            964 | 15-09-20 13:30:50 |
| 15-09-20 11:36:55                 | Adeel Hussain Scotts | 12546           |                    809 | 15-09-20 13:44:19 |                        0 |            459 | 15-09-20 13:51:58 |
| 15-09-20 11:36:55                 | Adeel Hussain Scotts | 12546           |                   1105 | 15-09-20 14:10:23 |                        0 |           1021 | 15-09-20 14:27:24 |
| 15-09-20 11:36:55                 | Adeel Hussain Scotts | 12546           |                   1206 | 15-09-20 14:47:30 |                        0 |             10 | 15-09-20 14:47:40 |
| 15-09-20 11:36:55                 | Adeel Hussain Scotts | 12546           |                    112 | 15-09-20 14:49:32 |                        0 |            533 | 15-09-20 14:58:25 |
| 15-09-20 13:30:56                 | Alex Quinn           | 28791           |                     92 | 15-09-20 13:32:28 |                        0 |           6551 | 15-09-20 15:21:40 |
| 15-09-20 13:30:56                 | Alex Quinn           | 28791           |                    344 | 15-09-20 15:27:24 |                        0 |           1019 | 15-09-20 15:44:23 |
| 15-09-20 13:30:56                 | Alex Quinn           | 28791           |                     61 | 15-09-20 15:45:24 |                        0 |           2052 | 15-09-20 16:19:37 |
| 15-09-20 13:30:56                 | Alex Quinn           | 28791           |                     60 | 15-09-20 16:20:37 |                        0 |            900 | 15-09-20 16:35:37 |
| 15-09-20 13:30:56                 | Alex Quinn           | 28791           |                   1820 | 15-09-20 17:05:55 |                        0 |           1348 | 15-09-20 17:28:23 |
| 15-09-20 13:30:56                 | Alex Quinn           | 28791           |                     16 | 15-09-20 17:28:39 |                        0 |           2387 | 15-09-20 18:08:26 |
| 15-09-20 13:30:56                 | Alex Quinn           | 28791           |                   1354 | 15-09-20 18:31:00 |                        0 |            357 | 15-09-20 18:36:57 |
| 15-09-20 13:30:56                 | Alex Quinn           | 28791           |                    256 | 15-09-20 18:41:13 |                        0 |           2515 | 15-09-20 19:23:07 |
| 15-09-20 13:30:56                 | Alex Quinn           | 28791           |                    318 | 15-09-20 19:28:25 |                        0 |           6118 | 15-09-20 21:10:23 |
| 15-09-20 13:30:56                 | Alex Quinn           | 28791           |                    243 | 15-09-20 21:14:26 |                      172 |            978 | 15-09-20 21:30:44 |
```

I want to create a SQL query that returns just the Date and User Name with the earliest logon time and the latest log off time. Something that looks like this

```
+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    Date           |      User Name       | First Logon Time  | Last Logoff Time  |
+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 15-09-20          | Aaisha Alvi Scotts   | 15-09-20 9:03:46  | 15-09-20 16:52:00 |
| 15-09-20          | Aaron Haider         | 15-09-20 8:00:15  | 15-09-20 16:09:15 |
| 15-09-20          | Adeel Hussain Scotts | 15-09-20 11:31:56 | 15-09-20 14:58:25 |
| 15-09-20          | Alex Quinn           | 15-09-20 13:32:28 | 15-09-20 21:30:44 |
+-------------------+----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Unfortunately as you can see there isn't a uniform number of logons for a given time duration and they don't follow consistently from one another. Also I will need to run it for multiple dates each of which is likely to have the same User Name appear multiple times so I'm having a real headache trying to conceptualize how to get the data into the preferred format. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Why doesn't `MIN` and `MAX` achieve this?

Comment: will that not just pick the min and max of all the dates though? I need each date to have it's own min and max maybe I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: You'd have to include a `GROUP BY` to dictate the grouping. Something like `SELECT convert(date, Signon_Time) as Date, UserName, Min(logon), Max(logoff) FROM tableName GROUP BY convert(date, signon_time), username`. That would retrieve the earliest logon, and the latest logoff, for each day, and each user. Hopefully that gets you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast your `datetime` to a `date` and use it in the `group by`:

```
SELECT CAST(SignOnTime AS DATE) , UserName,MIN(LogonTime),MAX(LogoffTime)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY CAST(SignOnTime AS DATE) , UserName
```